# No Progress after Click on Search Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping task using selenium and stuck at click function.

Steps in Website:
1. Open Website
2. Enter Key value in the search text box
3. Click on Search to start the search process

After step 3 it is supposed to load the progress bar and start searching for results. 
However, after clicking on search, Progress Bar appears for a second and goes away.

My code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe')
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30000)
browser.get("labs.nccgroup.trust/typofinder/")
browser.find_element_by_id('host').send_keys("example.com")
elem=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='typogulator']/input[2]")
elem.click()
```

Comment: Does your script perhaps close after clicking the button? Maybe some test listeners close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try Use `WebDriverWait` after inserting value in search field.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://labs.nccgroup.trust/typofinder')
browser.find_element_by_id('host').send_keys("example.com")
ele=WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='submit'][@value='Search']")))
ele.click()
```